# find and replace everything before character jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to display client information on site side for that I'm displaying email and other information as well.

Here I have to replace all the characters before @ with * like

```
test@gmail.com
```

This is the example mail id I want result as

```
****@gmail.com
```

I tried below one only @ is replacing with *

```js
$('.element span').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  var text = $(this).text().replace('@', '*');
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <span>test@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for security purposes? I assume you realise this is VERY low security?

Comment: I have to agree with @mayersdesign you'd still be sending the full email address, all anyone would have to do is open their network tab.

Comment: ...or disable javascript and hit F5

Comment: @mayersdesign Is correct, the user can easily view the source of the page without the JS run, and if you'll use AJAX, they can see the results from the server via developer tools. You need to do it on the server side

Comment: he said that he is trying to remove so network tab will not give you complete mail-id, but this will stops working functionality of mail if it has.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Oh, so in that case there's any real privacy solution

Comment: @AlonEitan  for showing purpose he can do that(replace with ****) but if he is sending that mail id through ajax ,then instead of sending mail id send user-id and then fetch his mail id. this much only possible.

Comment: I'd almost like to hear from OP that they understand the security implications here! I trust this is just an exercise in what is possible, or for use on an internal admin panel or something?

Comment: @mayersdesign sure sounds like fake security to me...  the "and other information" really bothers me......like what exactly?? CC#s? lol

Comment: @DelightedD0D haha, maybe just the clear text logins for the email accounts? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution.

```js
$('.element span').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/.+(?=@)/g, '*'.repeat($(this).text().replace(/@.+/g, '').length)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
   <span>test@gmail.com</span>
</div>

<div class="element">
   <span>somethingelse@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, without regex:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(el){
    var text = el.innerText;
    var substr = text.substr(0, text.lastIndexOf('@'));
    el.innerText = text.replace(substr, '*'.repeat(substr.length));
});
```

```html
<p>testa@gmail.com</p>
<p>testb@gmail.com</p>
<p>testc@anymail.com</p>
<p>testwithmoreasterisks@gmail.com</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your jQuery script to following script:

```
$(function(){
    $('.element span').each(function() {
        var index = $(this).text().indexOf("@");
        var substring = $(this).text().substr(0, index);
        var otherpart = $(this).text().substr(index);

        for (var i = 0, len = substring.length; i < len; i++) {
            substring = substring.replace(substring[i], '*');
        }
        console.log(substring + otherpart);
        $(this).text(substring + otherpart);
    });
});
```

Let me know if it is works.

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="element">
<span>vinay.mbkumar@gmail.com</span>
</div>
<script>

function replaceRange(s, start, end, substitute) {
return s.substring(0, start) + substitute + s.substring(end);
}

$('.element span').each(function() {
var str = $(this).text();
console.log(str);
console.log(str.length)
var i = 0;
var ind = 0;
var text = "";
var repchar = "";
while (i < str.length) {
console.log(str.charAt(i));
if(str.charAt(i) == '@')
{
ind = i;
break;
}
i++;
}
console.log(ind);
 for (i = 0; i < ind; i++)
 {
repchar  += "*";
 }

 text = replaceRange(str, 0, i , repchar); 
  console.log(text);
  $(this).text(text);
   });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a solution

`var strArray = ("test@gmail.com").split("@");
 var str = strArray[0].replace(/./gi, '*');
 str =str +"@"+ strArray[1];`